# Cоздать обьект юзера с ключами?

Tags: vue.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
   create() {
    var persons= {
    id: this.id,
    name: this.name,
    email: this.email,
    website: this.website
    }
   }
  },
  methods: {
   clickInfo: function () {
    btn: false;
    console.log(persons);
   }
  },
  data() {
   return {
    btn: true, 
    id: '11',
    name: 'Yark',
    email: 'yark.studio98@y.com',
    website: 'google.com'
   }
  }
 })
```

```html
 <div id="app">
  <ul>
   <!-- <li v-for="person in persons">{{person}}</li> -->
   <button v-show="btn" @click="clickInfo">Show information</button>
  </ul>
 </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

создать обьект юзера с ключами
    **id
    name**
+добавить кнопку инфо около каждого юзера
при клике на инфо - информация о человека

Answer (score 2):

Он тебе пишет что что локальная переменная "persons" не найдена!
Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: persons"

В коде надо использовать - this.persons!

Для обработки массива используй v-for, если ты используешь динамичное изменение массива то с ключем v-bind:key где будет уникальное значение.

Для вывода блоков с схожим контекстом - лучше всего использовать компоненты. Как передать props и вернуть events в примере тоже есть. Важно понимать что компоненты не должны влиять на верхний объект напрямую - лучше всего это делать через $emit.

ps: Если не нравиться темплейт компонентов в JS, то можно воспользоваться этим - https://jsfiddle.net/coligo/fjpqz387/ фиддлом и отделить HTML от JS полностью.

```js
const InformationButton = {
  name: "informationbutton",
  props: ['data'],
  data() {
    return {
      textMode: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    emitExample($event) {
      this.$emit('view-state-change', $event, this.textMode, this.data);
    }
  },
  template: `<span class="box">
  <span v-if="textMode">{{data}}</span>
  <span v-else>
    <button @click="textMode =! textMode; emitExample($event)">Show information</button>
  </span>
</span>`
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {         // Хочу отдельно заметить - у контроллера не нужен return
    persons: [{
      id: '11',
     name: 'Yark',
     email: 'yark.studio98@y.com',
     website: 'google.com'
    },{
      id: '12',
     name: 'Vinny Puh',
     email: 'puh.studio98@y.com',
     website: 'example.net/puh'
    }]
  },
  components: {
    informationbutton: InformationButton
  },
  methods: {
    onViewStateChanged($event, state, data) {
      console.log(state, data);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="person in persons" v-bind:key="person.id">
      <informationbutton v-bind:data="person" @view-state-change="onViewStateChanged" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: немного не так сначала мы отображаем параметры а потом ключи параметров

Comment: Persons изначально должны быть массивом - пусть хоть пустым. Ты его используешь в v-for... После уже можешь его заполнить через

this.persons.push(Object.assign({id: "newId"}, this.newPerson) где соответсвенно newPerson это ссылка на {{ newPerson.name }}, {{ newPerson.eMail }}

Comment: наверное но можно это без компонента написать пожалуйста по моим примером